# Defining a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to define a nested dictionary in python. I tried the following:

```
keyword = 'MyTest' # Later I want to pull this iterating through a list
key = 'test1'
sections = dict(keyword={}) #This is clearly wrong but how do I get the string representation?
sections[keyword][key] = 'Some value'
```

I can do this:

```
sections = {}
sections[keyword] = {}
```

But then there is a warning in the Pycharm saying it can be defined through dictionary label.

Can someone point out how to achieve this?

Comment: So... `sections = {keyword: {}}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
keyword = 'MyTest' # Later I want to pull this iterating through a list
key = 'test1'
sections = {keyword: {}} 
sections[keyword][key] = 'Some value'

print(sections)
{'MyTest': {'test1': 'Some value'}}
```

`dict(keyword={})` creates a dict with the string `"keyword"` as the key not the value of the variable keyword.

```
In [3]: dict(foo={})
Out[3]: {'foo': {}}
```

Where using a dict literal actually uses the value of the variable as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
sections = {}

keyword = 'MyTest'
# If keyword isn't yet a key in the sections dict, 
# add it and set the value to an empty dict
if keyword not in sections:
    sections[keyword] = {} 

key = 'test1'
sections[keyword][key] = 'Some value'
```

Alternativly you could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which will automatically create the inner dictionary the first time a keyword is accessed

```
from collections import defaultdict

sections = defaultdict(dict)

keyword = 'MyTest'
key = 'test1'
sections[keyword][key] = 'Some value'
```

Comment: Or use `setdefault` on a regular dictionary.