# Netsed dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to type a nested dictionary, but the results show the nested value with last entry. I guess this is because I'm trying to add the nested key with is the same for all:

```
for i in range(15, 19, 1):
    left_index = counters[i].find(']')
    right_index = counters[i].rfind(': ')
    key = counters[i][left_index + 1:right_index]
    value = counters[i][right_index + 1:].replace('[(','').replace(')]','').replace(') - (',' ').strip().split(' ')
    d1['value'] = value[0]
    d1['minimum'] = value[1]
    d1['maximum'] = value[-1]
    print 'key: ',key, 'value: ', d1
    d[key] = d1

encoder.FLOAT_REPR = lambda x: format(x, '.5f')
print json.dumps(d, indent=5, sort_keys=True)
```

And the result is:

```
key:   Socket/Modem 1/Bytes sent value:  {'minimum': '0', 'maximum': '2482262614', 'value': '2482262614'}
key:   Socket/Modem 1/recv value:  {'minimum': '0', 'maximum': '19646', 'value': '19646'}
key:   Socket/Modem 1/send value:  {'minimum': '0', 'maximum': '2078818', 'value': '2078818'}
key:   StreamerEngine/Bonding/Priority queue/Packets of '' priority dequeued value:  {'minimum': '0', 'maximum': '0', 'value': '0'}


{
 " Socket/Modem 1/Bytes sent": {
      "maximum": "0",
      "minimum": "0",
      "value": "0"
 },
 " Socket/Modem 1/recv": {
      "maximum": "0",
      "minimum": "0",
      "value": "0"
 },
 " Socket/Modem 1/send": {
      "maximum": "0",
      "minimum": "0",
      "value": "0"
 },
 " StreamerEngine/Bonding/Priority queue/Packets of '' priority dequeued": {
      "maximum": "0",
      "minimum": "0",
      "value": "0"
 }
}
```

So you can see that the `d1` dictionary is typed well but the accumulated dictionary `d` is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a nested dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131569/defining-a-nested-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d1` is (probably) declared outside of your loop, so you are using the **same object** again and again, that's why the last assigned values are used in all other dicts.

Instead define `d1` inside your loop:

```
for i in range(15, 19, 1):
    left_index = counters[i].find(']')
    right_index = counters[i].rfind(': ')
    key = counters[i][left_index + 1:right_index]
    value = counters[i][right_index + 1:].replace('[(','').replace(')]','').replace(') - (',' ').strip().split(' ')
    d1 = {} # <- new dict!
    d1['value'] = value[0]
    d1['minimum'] = value[1]
    d1['maximum'] = value[-1]
    print 'key: ',key, 'value: ', d1
    d[key] = d1
```